# #R is coming in output

Tags: c

My question was to find the roots of a quadratic equation. Everything was correct until where I have to find the imaginary roots and #R is coming

enter code here

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <math.h>

void main()

{

    int a,b,c;
    double r1,r2;

    printf("Enter a,b and c \n");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    double n=sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c);
    if (n>0)
    {
        r1=(-b+n)/(2*a);
        r2=(-b-n)/(2*a);
        printf("%.2lf \n",r1);
        printf("%.2lf",r2);
    }
    else if(n==0)
    {
        r1=(-b)/(2*a);
        printf("%.2lf",r1);
    }
    else
    {
        double d1=-b/(2*a);
        double d2=-n/(2*a);
        printf("%.2lf + i%.2lf \n",d1,d2);
        printf("%.2lf - i%.2lf \n",d1,d2);
    }
    getch();
}


input:1
      4
      9


Output-
2.00 + i1.#R
-2.00 - i1.#R
```

So why this #R is coming?

Comment: Please do not spam question programming language tags. This question appears to have nothing to do with Java or Python programming.

Comment: What is the square root of a *negative number*?

Comment: You are seeing `printf` attempting to display `1.#QNAN` but with rounding! There's no formal answer (so I can't flag as a duplicate) but the comment by Hans Passant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55420724/10871073) is relevant.